# Create class instance from string

Tags: c#, reflection, class, instance, argumentnullexception

I have a C# method which creates a new instance of a class from a string, however, I get an error when running the code.

```
obj = (ClassX)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("classPrefix_" + className));
```

> ArgumentNullException was unhandled
>
> Value cannot be null
>
> Parameter name: **type**

Any help on this error would be appreciated.

Comment: Well... Does the class "classPrefix_????" exist? If it doesn't then Type.GetType will return null...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may need to use the assembly qualified name as the argument to Type.GetType

```
eg AssemblyName.Namespace.ClassName
```

[MSDN Doc on assembly qualified names](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

Comment: The FQTN is Namespace.Class,Assembly i.e. the assembly name goes at the end and is separated by a comma (not at the front and separated by a dot).

Comment: Thanks. I had to put `Namespace.className`

Comment: @Tim Cooper - No problem, glad to help  




@itowlson - Thanks, I have updated my answer to correct my terminology.

Answer (score 3):

You may just be missing the namespace from the classname

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:

```
class ClassX {}
class classPrefix_x : ClassX {}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string className = "x";
        ClassX obj = (ClassX)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("classPrefix_" + className));
        Console.WriteLine(obj);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
classPrefix_x
```

The class you are looking for must not be defined. Are you sure you typed it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `Type.GetType("classPrefix_" + className)` call is returning a `null`. This is causing the `ArgumentNullException` when passed to the `CreateInstance` method.

Evaluate `"classPrefix_" + className` and check that you do have a type called what it evaluates to.

You also should be specifying the [AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) when using the [Type.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) method (ie. the fully qualified type name including the assembly name and namespace).

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a type of "classPrefix_" plus whatever you have on className. The Type.GetType() call returns null and CreateInstance throws the ArgumentNullException.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `Type.GetType(classHere)` didn't find anything, are you sure that the classname you're after exists?  Remember it should be prefixed with a namespace if possible, and won't be found in an external assembly unless it's already loaded in the App domain.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Type.GetType("classPrefix_" + className)` is returning null.

This returns null when it cannot find the type. A couple of possible causes are missing namespace, or the assembly the class is in is not loaded yet.

The Api documentation on the method which may give some more insite.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx